# Removing dead Facebook api tokens

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am trying to find a way to automatically validate multiple facebook access tokens at once.
I am storing user access tokens into a txt file and (as expected) after some time some of the tokens will expire or becomes invalid. (due to user change password/de-authorized app, log out, etc.)
Is there any way to check/validate all access tokens and delete those tokens that are invalid: doing this manually for more than 100 tokens is very difficult.
Options

checking access tokens from a .txt file (using PHP) and remove invalid tokens simultaneously so that at the end we will have a list with only valid tokens.
directly remove invalid tokens from the database.

I know the error is  for invalid tokens:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=AAABZCCkTsCEIBABLlG3w7q7X7QxN1Kw6yICsyArILfciDb7zdFMVoRaZCLrZC23lnZCg73pIBEavZBlZCBvSQVuanAffltasYZCqEjOmpsXHgZDZD

```
"type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 460
```

I'm looking for a way to automate this in curl

Answer (score 1):

Use `https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` where access_token is the application access token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/

As described in the link you should have error handling setup for token invalidations